# Type Error When Inserting User with bson-objectid into MongoDB Collection

Tags: mongodb, next.js, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm facing a type error while trying to insert a user object into a MongoDB collection using the insertOne method. The error seems to be related to the compatibility between the _id property of my User object and the expected type in the MongoDB driver.

I'm using TypeScript for my project and have a User interface defined with an _id property of type ObjectId from the `bson-objectid` library. The type definitions for ObjectId in the library are correctly imported and used consistently throughout my codebase.

However, when I attempt to insert a user using the following code:

```js
import { ObjectId } from 'bson-objectid';

export interface User {
  _id: ObjectId;
  // Other properties of User
}

// ... other code ...

await db.collection('users').insertOne(user);
```

I encounter the following type error:

```
./pages/api/auth/registerEmail.ts:37:41
Type error: Argument of type 'User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OptionalId<Document>'.
  Type 'User' is not assignable to type '{ _id?: ObjectId; }'.
    Types of property '_id' are incompatible.
      Type 'ObjectID' is not assignable to type 'ObjectId'.

  35 |          verificationToken,
  36 |  }
> 37 |  await db.collection('users').insertOne(user)
     |                                         ^
  38 |  const gender = await setUserGender(db, user)
  39 |  const payload = new JwtPayload(user)
  40 |  if (!process.env.JWT_SECRET) {

> Build error occurred

    await db.collection('users').insertOne(user)
```

I've confirmed that I'm using the ObjectId type consistently throughout my codebase, and I'm importing it from bson-objectid as shown above. The expected _id type in the MongoDB driver seems to be the same as the one from bson-objectid, so I'm unsure why this type mismatch is occurring.

I've also ensured that I've properly installed the bson-objectid library using npm.

Could anyone help me understand what might be causing this type error and how I can resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like somewhere along the way, the bson library changed the definition of their ObjectId type.  The important thing is that what you need to do is update your libraries to the latest versions.  Mongodb, for example, uses the bson library so using the latest "^6.2.0" of mongodb worked for me.